# VS 2010 Autocomplete not recognizing control (asp.net or Telerik) added in DataList ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, webforms

I have a webform that essentially has the following design:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
         <asp:DataList>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:LinkButton>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonItemTemplate" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonBeforeFormEndTag" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</form>
```

From the *Toolbox*, I *drag & dropped* two `asp:Button` controls: one just before the `</form>` end tag (ID `ButtonBeforeFormEndTag`) and one inside `DataList.ItemTemplate` (ID `ButtonItemTemplate`).

In `Page_Load` codebehind, I just added code like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonBeforeFormEndTag.Text = "Placed Form End Tag";
    ButtonItemTemplate.Text = "Placed in Item Template";
}
```

During the *Build*, I get error `The name 'ButtonItemTemplate' does not exist in the current context`.

I've tried to add it in the webform design, in the webform markup, and I've tried to move the control markup from the one place where it's created correctly to `ItemTemplate`, but as soon as it's moved in there, it just ceases to exist. `ItemTemplate`'s like the twilight zone for any control.

I would understand if none of the controls is recognized in *autocomplete*, but don't know why VS recognizes one but not the other.

So my question: why is the control recognized outside the `DataList` but not within `DataList.ItemTemplate`?

The reason for doing this is that the `Telerik RadButton` has a [reported issue](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-data-bind-in-contenttemplate-of-radbutton) with `ContentTemplate` when placed in a control that uses `ItemTemplate`, like a `DataList`.

The workaround was to set the content of the button control on the code-behind, which this accomplishes, since it can't be done in `Page_Load`, which is what Telerik suggests. But I can't set the Telerik control because autocomplete is not recognizing the control within `ItemTemplate`.

Thanks.

Comment: This is because the DataList contains repeating content. For each record in the DataList, a button called "ButtonItemTemplate" will be created. ASP.NET handles this by giving them unique names when rendered on the page. Since they get unique names, no control by the name of "ButtonItemTemplate" actually exists. If you view the source of the page after it is rendered, you will see these names. They may look something like "dataList_ButtonItemTemplate_0", "dataList_ButtonItemTemplate_1", etc.

Comment: Is it possible to access them from `Page_Load`? For example, `ButtonItemTemplate.Text` to _This is my ItemTemplate_.

Comment: Like un-lucky said, it is possible if you first bind the DataList, then iterate each item. But just straight away, no you cannot as it does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access them directly, since it is inside the `<ItemTemplate>`, so the simple way is to use `OnItemDataBound` event of the DataList. Which can be implemented like the following:

Changes in the markup:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound">.... </asp:DataList>
```

**c#**

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Button btnTemplate = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("ButtonItemTemplate");
        if (btnTemplate != null) { btnTemplate.Text = "Placed Form End Tag"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to access them from `Page_Load`? For example, `ButtonItemTemplate.Text` to _This is my ItemTemplate_.

Comment: Straight answer is no, but it is possible if you bind the `DataList` in pageLoad

Comment: Thanks. Worked well.

Comment: The issue was that  the `RadButton` has a problem with `ContentTemplate` when placed in a control that uses `ItemTemplate`, like a `DataList`. The workaround was to set the content of the button control on the code-behind, which this accomplishes, since it can't be done in `Page_Load`, which is what Telerik suggests.